# Update completion handler outside declared method

Tags: ios, objective-c, completion-block

I have been trying various solutions to get an updated value of `handler` from `methodTwo` and `methodThree`. The code starts with `methodOne()`, followed by `methodTwo()`. How to approach this puzzle?

These methods are declared inside a static library. And its reference implementation i.e. a SampleApp.xcodeproj is calling `methodOne()`, which is exposed in the header files of the static library.

I have looked into *KVO* and *NSNotificationCenter*, but it seems that the direction is not correct.

```
-(void)methodOne: completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))handler {
    // Step 1
    // Open view controller from PayPal-iOS-SDK
    // BOOL = handlerStatus;

    if (handler != nil)
        handler(handlerStatus);
}

-(void)methodTwo {
    // Step 2   
    // Delegate method from PayPal-iOS-SDK (executed after methodOne())
    // Generates a code which needs to be sent to server to get success/fail
    // Call methodThree to update handlerStatus 
}

-(NSString*) methodThree {
    // Step 3
    // Returns success/fail i.e. handler value
    // Network call (sending code to server)
}
```

**Update**

I wanted to use a completion handler, since that's not working. I have to resolve this issue by using delegation as a messaging protocol.

Comment: Huh? Please clarify. What's calling these methods?

Comment: @rmaddy Forgive me. I updated the question. A reference implementation is calling methodOne().